# tap behaviour not consistent on iOS with disableSynchroniztion

Tags: ios, react-native, testing, mobile, detox

I have a test which uses a WebView to login to the application (done in a hacky way by using a text input with a button + `injectedJavaScript` as WebView instrumentation is not supported).

The problem appears because the login operation inside the WebView happens asynchronously and breaks the Detox synchronization, so I have to manage it myself manually with `disableSynchronization` and `enableSynchronization`.
After the login I have a stack transition animation to a new screen (from react-navigation) and I need to press a button on that screen to go further. However Detox still fails to synchronize with that screen so I am using tap to press on the button with synchronization disabled.

**This is where the problem happens, the tap doesn't always work, and in 50% of the time just fails with a timeout for any action done after the `disableSynchronization` call. This makes the tests flaky and pretty much useless**

Can anyone recommend a workaround or knows what the problem is?

Environment 
Detox: 12.10.3.
React Native: 0.59.8
Node: v11.7.0
Device: iOS Emulator (iPhone 8)
OS: iOS

I tried disabling and enabling the synchronisation before and after the tap on the button but it did not help, and in fact made the test fail with a timeout.

The code of my login method:

```
export const loginAs = async (userID) => {
  await element(by.id('introLoginBtn')).tap();
  await expect(element(by.id('loginScreen'))).toBeVisible();

  const userIdInput = element(by.id('testUserIdInput'));
  await userIdInput.tap();
  await userIdInput.typeText(userID);
  await element(by.id('testLoginBtn')).tap();

  // NOTE: WebView login breaks synchronization see 
  // https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md
  await device.disableSynchronization();

  // Waiting for the element to be visible
  await waitFor(element(by.id('acceptTermsBtn'))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(9000);

  // This does not work consistently
  await element(by.id('acceptTermsBtn')).tap();

  await device.enableSynchronization();
};
```

When I get in the debug console with `--debug-synchronization 200`:

```
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timer: Tracking Timer <__NSCFTimer: 0x600003e6de00>
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: performSelector @selector(removeInactiveFingerTips) on DTXTouchVisualizerWindow
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync App State: undefined
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: performSelector @selector(removeFromSuperview) on COSTouchSpotView
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: performSelector @selector(removeInactiveFingerTips) on DTXTouchVisualizerWindow
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync App State: undefined
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: performSelector @selector(removeInactiveFingerTips) on DTXTouchVisualizerWindow
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: performSelector @selector(removeFromSuperview) on COSTouchSpotView
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync App State: undefined
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: performSelector @selector(removeInactiveFingerTips) on DTXTouchVisualizerWindow
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: performSelector @selector(removeFromSuperview) on COSTouchSpotView
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXAnimatedDisplayLinkIdlingResource: undefined
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync App State: undefined
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Timed: performSelector @selector(removeInactiveFingerTips) on DTXTouchVisualizerWindow
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXAnimatedDisplayLinkIdlingResource: undefined
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync WXAnimatedDisplayLinkIdlingResource: undefined
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread
detox[33941] INFO:  [actions.js] Sync JavaScript Timers: Javascript Timers
```

The last 3 lines repeat until the test times out.

and after launching with`launchArgs: { 'detoxPrintBusyIdleResources': 'YES' }` and running `xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level debug --style compact --predicate "category=='EarlGreyStatistics'"`:

```
Error from getpwuid_r: 0 (Undefined error: 0)
Filtering the log data using "category == "EarlGreyStatistics""
```

Comment: What reason do you have to disable synchronization?

Comment: I have a test that uses script injection to bypass the login step which happens inside a WebView. After that I am triggering a navigation action to a native screen but the matchers can't find any elements on it unless I disable synchronisation. Then they can, but it's flaky and fails 50% of the time by just timing out in a sync-dispatch loop.

Comment: Injecting code into a web view should not require disabling synchronization. If you see a loop, it means your app is busy. In anyway, what does the error tell you when you try to tap the button?

Comment: There is not error, the test just times out. If I change my app and navigate to a screen in another stack navigator (from react-navigation) the sync issue goes away.

Comment: You can enable various synchronization debug features to help you out. This is what I meant by “error”.

Comment: I updated the question with the debug logs that I get for this problem. They don't really speak to me much..

Comment: Right, the log you have posted seems like a classic endless animation. Do you have something like that? I'd recommend mocking that to not be endless if testing.

Comment: You might be right, it's possible I have a mounted modal with a loading animation under the screen I am showing. Will try to mock it and see of it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was indeed caused by an animation that was running in an infinite loop as [Leo Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983912/leo-natan) mentioned.

I had a screen that was mounted under the current one in a stack navigator from `react-navigation`. Unmounting the stack (and the endlessly animated  screen) with `reset` solved the problem.

Comment: Where/how did you do `reset`?

Comment: I am using react-navigation', so I call `navigation.reset()` when navigating to unmount the current screen (which is constantly animating)